# Repeated offset of line along vector and output of point tour

Tags: graphics, coordinate-transformation

I would like to make a number of copies of a line along a vector (with a specified spacing) and then output a list of points at each end of the line sequenced in a back-and-forth tour. Any help is appreciated.

```
vectA = {{-84.1359618960596, 35.97958565701818}, {-84.13634868468266, 
35.98034201650304}};
vectB = {{-84.1359618960596, 35.97958565701818}, {-84.1368965723382, 
35.9792691449989}};

Graphics[Line[Join[vectB, vectA]]]
```

**Update:** For additional clarity, points 4, 5, 8, 9 need to lie on the same line as vectB and each copied line needs to be the same length as vectA.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- we set `e1` and `e2` as two basis

```
Clear[vectA, vectB, original, a, b, e1, e2];
vectA = {{-84.1359618960596, 35.97958565701818}, {-84.13634868468266, 
    35.98034201650304}};
vectB = {{-84.1359618960596, 35.97958565701818}, {-84.1368965723382, 
    35.9792691449989}};
{original, a} = vectA;
{original, b} = vectB;
e1 = a - original;
e2 = b - original;

t = Subdivide[0, 1, 10];
(*t=Join[{0},Sort@RandomReal[{0,1},8],{1}];*)

pairs = Table[
   If[OddQ[i], Identity, Reverse]@{original + t[[i]]*e2, 
     original + t[[i]]*e2 + e1}, {i, 1, Length@t}];
pts = Flatten[pairs, 1];
Graphics[{Green, Arrow /@ pairs, Brown, 
  MapIndexed[Text[Last@#2, #1, {1, 1}] &, pts], {Blue, 
   Line[{original, b}]}, {Red, Line[{original, a}]}}]
```

[image]

Comment: (+1) yup! much better than mine!!!

Comment: @bmf  Thanks! But when I want to control the position of the labels, I cann't find a better way.

Comment: I think it's sufficiently clear as an approach

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps the following?

```
vectA = {{-84.1359618960596, 35.97958565701818}, {-84.13634868468266, 
    35.98034201650304}};
vectB = {{-84.1359618960596, 35.97958565701818}, {-84.1368965723382, 
    35.9792691449989}};
g1 = Graphics[Line[Join[vectB, vectA]]];
g2 = Graphics@{
    Line[{{84.1359618960596, -84.1359618960596}, {35.97958565701818, 
       35.98034201650304}}],
    Line[{{94.1359618960596, -84.1359618960596}, {45.97958565701818, 
       35.98034201650304}}],
    Line[{{104.1359618960596, -84.1359618960596}, {55.97958565701818, 
       35.98034201650304}}],
    Inset[
     Text[Style["1", Large, 
       Red]], {84.1359618960596, -84.1359618960596}, Scaled[{.9, .5}]],
    Inset[
     Text[Style["2", Large, Red]], {35.97958565701818, 
      35.98034201650304}, Scaled[{.9, .5}]],
    Inset[
     Text[Style["3", Large, 
       Green]], {94.1359618960596, -84.1359618960596}, 
     Scaled[{.9, .5}]],
    Inset[
     Text[Style["4", Large, Green]], {45.97958565701818, 
      35.98034201650304}, Scaled[{.9, .5}]],
    Inset[
     Text[Style["5", Large, 
       Magenta]], {104.1359618960596, -84.1359618960596}, 
     Scaled[{.9, .5}]],
    Inset[
     Text[Style["6", Large, Magenta]], {55.97958565701818, 
      35.98034201650304}, Scaled[{.9, .5}]]
    };
Overlay@{g1, g2}
```

> [image: graphics]

and you can customize easily I think

Comment: I added an update to clarify my request. Thanks!

Comment: @Young I got what you meant, but I wanted to say that you can easily modify the lengths and the markers by using my answer. It shouldn't be too hard

Comment: Understood, but I was hoping for something more automatic and parameterized so that it could be done on many sets without fine adjustment of each one.